# Calculate order of items in R using data.table

Tags: r, count, data.table

I want to know how many id's have different types in different orders. For example, I have a dataset like below:

```
data <- data.table( id      = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                    type    = c(3,3,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3), 
                    nr_item = c(1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3))
```

I would like to know how many id's have type 1 first (nr_item = 1). Then I'd like to know how many id's have first (nr_item = 1) type 1 and then again (nr_item = 2) type 1. And then, how many have first (nr_item = 1) type 1 and then again (nr_item = 2) type 1 and then again type 1 (nr_item = 2) etc..

I'd like to know this for all possible combinations and successions.

The result should have a count of amount of id's in the order/shape like this:

```
1
1 -> 1
1 -> 1 -> 1
1 -> 1 -> 2
1 -> 1 -> 3
1 -> 2
1 -> 2 -> 1
1 -> 2 -> 2
1 -> 2 -> 3
etc..
```

Note that some id's have double mentions, they should then also be counted double, if they result in a switch in different type. For example id 1 starts twice with type 3, this can be ignored. But id 5 has both type 2 and type 3 as their second nr_item, this should be regarded as two seperate occasions to count.

Comment: Your explanation of how to count is not clear to me, namely the third sentence: *"first (nr_item = 1) type 1 and then again (nr_item = 2) type 1 and then again type 1 (nr_item = 2)"*. Please give a *literal* R structure of expected output (with real counts), as your *"order/shape"* does not make sense to me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to count all possible paths given by `data`.

Here is a first attempt

```
library(data.table)
data[, CJ(type1 = .SD[nr_item == 1, type], 
          type2 = .SD[nr_item == 2, type], 
          type3 = .SD[nr_item == 3, type], unique = TRUE), by = id][
            , rollup(.SD, list(count=.N), by = c("type1", "type2", "type3"))][
              order(type1, type2, type3, na.last = FALSE)]
```

> ```
>     type1 type2 type3 count
>  1:    NA    NA    NA     6
>  2:     1    NA    NA     1
>  3:     1     2    NA     1
>  4:     1     2     3     1
>  5:     2    NA    NA     1
>  6:     2     2    NA     1
>  7:     2     2     3     1
>  8:     3    NA    NA     4
>  9:     3     2    NA     2
> 10:     3     2     3     2
> 11:     3     3    NA     2
> 12:     3     3     3     2
> ```

The possible paths are created by

```
data[, CJ(type1 = .SD[nr_item == 1, type], 
          type2 = .SD[nr_item == 2, type], 
          type3 = .SD[nr_item == 3, type], unique = TRUE), by = id]
```

> ```
>    id type1 type2 type3
> 1:  1     3     3     3
> 2:  2     3     2     3
> 3:  3     1     2     3
> 4:  4     2     2     3
> 5:  5     3     2     3
> 6:  5     3     3     3
> ```

So, there are 6 paths in total of which 4 paths start with *type* `3` and 2 paths start with *types* `3 -> 2`, e.g.

#### EDIT: Fine-tune the output

In order to make the result look more like OP's expected result the output of `rollup()` can be modified:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
cols <- paste0("type", 1:3)
data[, CJ(type1 = .SD[nr_item == 1, type], 
          type2 = .SD[nr_item == 2, type], 
          type3 = .SD[nr_item == 3, type], unique = TRUE), by = id][
            , rollup(.SD, list(count = .N), by = cols)][
              , .(path = unlist(.SD) %>% 
                    na.omit() %>% 
                    paste(collapse = " -> "), 
                  count), 
              .SDcols = cols, by = .(rn = seq_along(count))][
                , path := path %>% str_pad(max(str_length(.)), "right")][
                  order(path), -"rn"]
```

> ```
>            path count
>  1:                 6
>  2: 1               1
>  3: 1 -> 2          1
>  4: 1 -> 2 -> 3     1
>  5: 2               1
>  6: 2 -> 2          1
>  7: 2 -> 2 -> 3     1
>  8: 3               4
>  9: 3 -> 2          2
> 10: 3 -> 2 -> 3     2
> 11: 3 -> 3          2
> 12: 3 -> 3 -> 3     2
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use table function to have a pivot table

```
table(data$type, data$nr_item)
```

BTW if you just wanna summarise that data you can use these. almost identical results.

```
table(data$type)
```

or summarise from dplyr package

```
data %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   summarise(count = n())
```

finally, if you want to data.table itself you can use this

```
data[,.(count = .N), by = type]
```

Comment: Please test those and let me know which one doesn't work. I'm teaching R and python for almost 5 years and had more than 1500 students. Although the problem definition was abit vague, I tride to answer as i understand the question. So... Im puzzled about your comment too.  Try to be nicer time to time

Comment: Of course, I have tested your code before I had posted my comment! For instance, your code `data[,.(count = sum(nr_time)), by = type]` gives the error message *Error in `[.data.table`(data, , .(count = sum(nr_time)), by = type) : 
  object 'nr_time' not found*.

Comment: you are rigth. obviously thats a typo. corrected. thanks